# Packing and unpacking a value into bits Arduino-Matlab

Tags: matlab, arduino

I have been reading several threads but I am still not sure how to accomplish this. I am reading some values in Arduino with analogRead(), so I am getting values between 0-1023 and I am sending them to Matlab via Serial Communiaction. I am currently using Serial.print(), but I have read that it is a much more efficient way to use Serial.write(): by packing first the value into bits and only sending the MSB and the LSB. This way I will use less bits to send one value than in the case of using Serial.print.

The thing is that I don't know how I can pack the values (0-1023) in Arduino to send the MSB and LSB and then unpacking them in MATLAB to define the integer value again.

Coud you please give me a hand?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First in C/C++ on the Arduino, you can get the most significant bit (MSB) or least significant bit (LSB) via the [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) of [bit shifting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) and [bit masking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)):

```
const word Value = 1000;   // Could also be an int or an unsigned int, [0-1023]
byte MSB = Value >> 8;     // Right shift
byte LSB = Value & 0x00FF; // Mask
```

However, Arduino, being Arduino, has functions for these: [`highByte`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/HighByte) and [`lowByte`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/LowByte) return the MSB and LSB of a value, respectively.

I can't really say if using `Serial.Write` will be faster for you. If you're sending lots of data to Matlab, it's best to limit the number of calls to either `Serial.Write` or `Serial.Print`. You can do this by creating a buffer (a byte array), sticking all of the data in it, and then passing the upper to `Serial.Write` (see the documentation for the overloaded version of this function).

On the Matlab side there are equivalent [bitwise functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/bitwise-operations.html), just don't expect them to be as efficient as their C counterparts. They are useful for testing an prototyping though. For example, you can reproduce the above C code in Matlab with:

```
Value = uint16(1000);
MSB = bitshift(Value,-8); % Right shift
LSB = bitand(Value,255);  % Mask
```

You "reassemble" your two-byte value by reversing the bit-wise operations:

```
Value = bitor(bitshift(MSB,8),LSB)
```

In C this is just `(MSB<<8)|LSB` and you can implement the above more efficiently in Matlab with:

```
Value = MSB*256+LSB
```